# Can I say "less good than"?

Tags: grammar

When two things or people are both good and I don't want to express any negativity in the comparison. Can I say Bill is less good than Joshua?

Comment: That sounds rude. You could say, "Joshua is better than Bill"

Comment: Rude or not, we just don''t usually use "less good" like that. We'd much more likely say *Bill is **worse** than Joshua* - OR *Bill **isn't as good as** Joshua.* By the same token, we wouldn't usually say, for example, *Bill is **less old** than Joshua* - that would be *Bill is **younger** than Joshua* OR *Bill **isn't as old as** Joshua*. It's meaningless to ask how you can say that someone isn't as good as someone else without "negativity". If you don't want to be negative about who's better or worse, just don't say *anything*.

Comment: You can say _less good than_ if _good_ has already been used in the discourse. _Jim is good at this, but Mary is less good._

Comment: @Weather Vane this seems to be the best solution to OP's issue:  reframe the statement in terms of the positive ("even better") instead of the negative ("less good/worse").  Have you considered posting this as an answer?

Comment: FumbleFingers, I'm ok with: Bill isn't as good as Joshua. But saying "Bill is worse than Joshua." sounds totally different for it means both are bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say, "Bill is less good than Joshua", this means that both Bill and Joshua are good, but Joshua is more good.

Usually we would simply say, "Joshua is better than Bill." If someone said "Bill is less good", I would probably interpret that as carefully choosing is words. He wants to make clear that he thinks both are good. But Joshua is MORE good. Bill might still be insulted, but he'd be less insulted than if you said "Joshua is better" or "Bill is bad".

I see someone suggested, "Bill is worse than Joshua". But that's not really the same thing. That implies that both are bad, and Bill is more bad.

Like if Joshua came in first in an Olympic competition and Bill came in second, I might say, "Joshua is better than Bill." Recognizing that coming in #2 means he's the second best in the world, quite an accomplishment, I might say "Bill is less good than Joshua." But I would not be likely to say "Bill is worse than Joshua." Now I might say something like, "Stalin was worse than Hitler", comparing two very bad people.

Comment: I totally agree with your analysis. When someone says "Bill is less good than Joshua." That person just doesn't want to mention that they are very good, they are both just good, but one of them is less good. If someone says Joshua is better than Bill, you won't understand the exact degree of their quality, you would think they are both very good.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compliment both the parties, I suggest

> Joshua is even better than Bill.
> Joshua has the edge on Bill.

This phrasing suggests that both are very good.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more appropriate to say, "Bill is not as good as Joshua." or, "Joshua is better than Bill."